# Container inside Material widget taking full screen height in flutter

Tags: flutter, containers

I am trying to implement a card-like overlay whose height will be dependent on the child texts.
This is the code of my flutter card overlay which is taking full-screen height. How should I fix it without declaring a constant height as the amount of text is variable.

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_overlay_window/flutter_overlay_window.dart';

class TrueCallerOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  const TrueCallerOverlay({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TrueCallerOverlay> createState() => _TrueCallerOverlayState();
}

class _TrueCallerOverlayState extends State<TrueCallerOverlay> {
  bool isGold = true;

  final _goldColors = const [
    Color.fromARGB(255, 51, 219, 79),
    Color.fromARGB(255, 151, 235, 169),
    Color.fromARGB(255, 15, 107, 35),
  ];

  final _silverColors = const [
    Color(0xFFAEB2B8),
    Color(0xFFC7C9CB),
    Color(0xFFD7D7D8),
    Color(0xFF003226),
  ];
  final bgColor = Color(0xFF003226);
  final textColor = Colors.white;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FlutterOverlayWindow.overlayListener.listen((event) {
      log("$event");
      setState(() {
        isGold = !isGold;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0),
          width: double.infinity,
          //height: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: bgColor,
            // gradient: LinearGradient(
            //   begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            //   end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            //   colors: isGold ? _goldColors : _silverColors,
            // ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
          ),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              FlutterOverlayWindow.shareData(
                  "Heyy this is a data from the overlay");
            },
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          "Attention",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 28,
                              color: textColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          "t1",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: textColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          "t2",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: textColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                        child: FlatButton(
                          child: Text(
                            'Reference',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          textColor: Colors.black,
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await FlutterOverlayWindow.closeOverlay();
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.close,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[this is the current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR2Jh.png)     [What I am expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICswq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just wrap your `Container` with `IntrinsicHeight` or `SingleChildScrollView`.

Comment: Cool man.Worked like a charm.